# Count the number of max values for several dates

Tags: mysql, sql, count

For a given user, I want to make a SQL query that returns the number of time the user had the best value for each day.
I use MySQL.

```
-----------------------------
| User |    Date    | Value |
-----------------------------
| John | 2013-04-03 | 57    |
| John | 2013-04-04 | 13    |
| John | 2013-04-05 | 102   |
| John | 2013-04-06 | 64    |
| Bob  | 2013-04-03 | 8     |
| Bob  | 2013-04-04 | 83    |
| Bob  | 2013-04-05 | 44    |
| Bob  | 2013-04-06 | 101   |
| Paul | 2013-04-03 | 22    |
| Paul | 2013-04-04 | 72    |
| Paul | 2013-04-05 | 50    |
| Paul | 2013-04-06 | 15    |
-----------------------------
```

**Example :**
John : 2 times (2013-04-03 & 2013-04-05)
Bob : 2 times (2013-04-04 & 2013-04-06)
Paul : 0 time

I don't know which functions I have to use (*COUNT(*)* ? *SUM(*)* ? *MAX(Value)* ? *GROUP BY* ?).
How can I make a loop for each date and make the sum ?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: What do you want to happen in the event of a tie?

Comment: I forgot to say that. I use MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned the RDBMS you are using, here's a query that will work on *almost all* RDBMS:

```
SELECT  aa.User, COUNT(bb.User ) TotalCount
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT User FROM TableName) aa
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.User
            FROM    TableName a
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT  Date, MAX(Value) max_val
                        FROM    TableName
                        GROUP   BY Date
                    ) b ON  a.Date = b.Date AND
                            a.Value = b.max_val
        ) bb ON aa.User = bb.User 
GROUP   BY aa.User
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7ea6/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦════════════╗
║ USER ║ TOTALCOUNT ║
╠══════╬════════════╣
║ Bob  ║          2 ║
║ John ║          2 ║
║ Paul ║          0 ║
╚══════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query to achive this -

```
WITH T AS (SELECT USER,COUNT(*) 
             FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE (DATE,VALUE) IN (SELECT DATE, MAX(VALUE) 
                                                      FROM TABLE_NAME 
                                                  GROUP BY DATE)
          GROUP BY USER)

SELECT * FROM T 
UNION SELECT USER,0 
        FROM TABLE_NAME 
       WHERE USER NOT IN (SELECT USER FROM T)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following

```
  select
   u.user, count(*) as top_performer
  from 
    my_table u
    join (
      select valdate, max(value) as value 
      from my_table 
      group by valdate
    ) mv on
      mv.valdate = u.valdate and
      mv.value = u.value
  group by
    u.user
```

JW's answer may be more complete because it lists Paul's Zero score - my answer, on the other hand,  assumes that you will `left join` to another table of users.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/409ca/11