# PHP Array : "group by" then count maximum

Tags: php, arrays, group-by, max

I already asked this question for [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921292/count-the-number-of-max-values-for-several-dates/15922320) , but I want to do the same thing with a PHP array now.

```
|--------|------------|--------|
|  Name  |    Date    | Points |
|--------|------------|--------|
| Tom    | 2013-05-19 | 23     |
| Tom    | 2013-05-20 | 11     |
| Tom    | 2013-05-21 | 40     |
| Jack   | 2013-05-19 | 34     |
| Jack   | 2013-05-20 | 15     |
| Jack   | 2013-05-21 | 28     |
| Arthur | 2013-05-19 | 9      |
| Arthur | 2013-05-20 | 12     |
| Arthur | 2013-05-21 | 42     |
| Bill   | 2013-05-19 | 27     |
| Bill   | 2013-05-20 | 23     |
| Bill   | 2013-05-21 | 19     |
| ...    | ...        | ...    |
```

For a given person, I want to know how many times he got first and how many times he got last.

I tried several things like this :

```
<?php
    $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT Name, Date, Points FROM quotes WHERE Date > ? AND Date < ?');
    $req->execute(array($_GET['datemin'], $_GET['datemax']));

    $retour=array();
    while ($donnees = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $retour[] = array('Date' => $donnees[Date], array(
            'Name' => $donnees[Name],
            'Points' => (float)$donnees[Points]
        ));

        // $key = array_search($donnees[Date], $retour);
        // var_dump($key);

        /*
        $retour[$i][] = array(
            'Name' => $donnees[Name],
            'Points' => (float)$donnees[Points]
        );
        */
    }

    $nb_first=0;
    $nb_last=0;

    // Input name : $_GET['id']

    /*
    foreach ($retour as $key_n1 => $value_n1) // Loop for each date
    {
        foreach ($value_n1 as $key_n2 => $value_n2) // For an unique day, compare the people's results
        {
            // Test here ?
        }
    }
    */

$send_value = array(
    'Nb_First' => $nb_first,
    'Nb_Last' => $nb_last
);

// var_dump($send_value);
echo json_encode($send_value);
?>
```

My idea was to use a 3-dimensional array by "grouping by" by date :

```
[01]
'Date' => '2013-05-19'
  | [01]
    | 'Name' => 'Tom'
    | 'Points' => '23'
  | [02]
    | 'Name' => 'Jack'
    | 'Points' => '34'
  | [03]
    | 'Name' => 'Arthur'
    | 'Points' => '9'
  | [04]
    | 'Name' => 'Bill'
    | 'Points' => '27'
[02]
'Date' => '2013-05-20'
  | [01]
    | 'Name' => 'Tom'
    | 'Points' => '11'
  | [02]
    | 'Name' => 'Jack'
    | 'Points' => '15'
[...]
```

Then, for each date, try to find if the given person (`$_GET['id']`) has the max value (then `$nb_first++;`) or the min value (then `$nb_last++;`).

Maybe there are some PHP functions that can help to do that. It's much easier to do that with a SQL query. :-(

Comment: I don't think there are any built-in functions, this is too specialized. You have to write a loop. But if you can do it in SQL, why do you need to do it in PHP?

Comment: I changed my answer. I thought it would be better to have just one loop and one array with all the data. I couldn't think of a reason why you would want the primary index to be numerical as you showed, so I indexed it with the date.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your array is something like the following:

```
$arr = array(   1 => array( 'Name'      => 'Tom',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-19',
                    'Points'    => '23'),
        2 => array( 'Name'      => 'Tom',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-20',
                    'Points'    => '11'),
        3 => array( 'Name'      => 'Tom',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-21',
                    'Points'    => '40'),
        4 => array( 'Name'      => 'Jack',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-19',
                    'Points'    => '34'),
        5 => array( 'Name'      => 'Jack',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-20',
                    'Points'    => '15'),
        6 => array( 'Name'      => 'Jack',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-21',
                    'Points'    => '28'),
        7 => array( 'Name'      => 'Arthur',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-19',
                    'Points'    => '9'),
        8 => array( 'Name'      => 'Arthur',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-20',
                    'Points'    => '12'),
        9 => array( 'Name'      => 'Arthur',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-21',
                    'Points'    => '42'),
        10 => array('Name'      => 'Bill',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-19',
                    'Points'    => '27'),
        11 => array('Name'      => 'Bill',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-20',
                    'Points'    => '23'),
        12 => array('Name'      => 'Bill',
                    'Date'      => '2013-05-21',
                    'Points'    => '19'));
```

You can generate something similar to what you're looking for with:

```
$dates = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    if (isset($dates[$value['Date']]['high'])){
        if ($value['Points'] >= $dates[$value['Date']]['high']){
            $dates[$value['Date']]['first'] = $value['Name'];
            $dates[$value['Date']]['high'] = $value['Points'];
        }
        if ($value['Points'] <= $dates[$value['Date']]['low']){
            $dates[$value['Date']]['last'] = $value['Name'];
            $dates[$value['Date']]['low'] = $value['Points'];
        }
    } else {
        $dates[$value['Date']]['first'] = $value['Name'];
        $dates[$value['Date']]['high'] = $value['Points'];
        $dates[$value['Date']]['last'] = $value['Name'];
        $dates[$value['Date']]['low'] = $value['Points'];
    }
    $dates[$value['Date']]['stats'][] = array(  'Name'      => $value['Name'],
                                                'Points'    => $value['Points']);
}
```